# How add 0´s in front of a number to make it 6 digits R

Tags: r

Ive found solutions for my problem in other code languages, but not in R.

I want to add 0s infront of numbers in a column in a data frame to make it 6 digits.

Eg

```
1331
221231
21311
```

I want to become

```
001331
221231
021311
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sprintf()` is a function to do c-like formatting, e.g.

```
sprintf("%06i",c(1331, 221231, 21311))
# [1] "001331" "221231" "021311"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called padding zeros.

The function `str_pad()` from the `stringr` library works like this:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_pad

```
df<-data.frame(zip=c(1,22,333,4444,55555))

df$zip <- stringr::str_pad(df$zip, width=5, pad = "0")
[1] "00001" "00022" "00333" "04444" "55555"
```